# Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert only owner can call this function

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

**Question**

Open the TestGaming.sol contract in the test folder. Write a test for the function
withdrawFunds .
Your test should check the balance of the owner who called the withdrawFunds function.
Your test should also verify if the owner’s balance has increased by 10 ether.

**Gaming.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Gaming {
    /* Our Online gaming contract */
    address public owner;
    bool public online;

    struct Player {
        uint wins;
        uint losses;
    }

    mapping (address => Player) public players;

    constructor() public payable {
        owner = msg.sender;
        online = true;
    }

    modifier isOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner can call this function");
        _;
    }

event GameFunded(address funder, uint amount);
    event PlayerWon(address player, uint amount, uint mysteryNumber, uint displayedNumber);
    event PlayerLost(address player, uint amount, uint mysteryNumber, uint displayedNumber);

    function mysteryNumber() internal view returns (uint) {
        uint randomNumber = uint(blockhash(block.number-1))%10 + 1;
        return randomNumber;
    }

    function determineWinner(uint number, uint display, bool guess) public pure returns (bool) {
        if (guess == true && number > display) {
            return true;
        } else if (guess == true && number < display) {
            return false;
        } else if (guess == false && number > display) {
            return false;
        } else if (guess == false && number < display) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    function winOrLose(uint display, bool guess) external payable returns (bool, uint) {
        /* Use true for a higher guess, false for a lower guess */
        require(online == true, "The game is online");
        require(msg.sender.balance > msg.value, "Insufficient funds");
        uint mysteryNumber_ = mysteryNumber();
        bool isWinner = determineWinner(mysteryNumber_, display, guess);
        Player storage player = players[msg.sender];
        /* Player Won */
        if (isWinner == true) {
            player.wins += 1;
            msg.sender.transfer(msg.value * 2);
            emit PlayerWon(msg.sender, msg.value, mysteryNumber_, display);
            return (true, mysteryNumber_);
          /* Player Lost */
        } else if (isWinner == false) {
            player.losses += 1;
            emit PlayerLost(msg.sender, msg.value, mysteryNumber_, display);
            return (false, mysteryNumber_);
        }
    }
```

**TestGaming**

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/Gaming.sol";

contract TestGaming {
    uint public initialBalance = 10 ether;
    Gaming gaming;
    address owner;

    function beforeAll() public {
        gaming = Gaming(DeployedAddresses.Gaming());
        owner = gaming.owner();

    }

    function testWithdrawFunds() public {
        sssssgaming.withdrawFunds();
        Assert.equal(initialBalance + 10 ether, owner.balance, "Owner's balance should have increased by 10 ether");
    }

    function testPlayerWonGuessHigher() public {
        bool expected = true;
        bool result = gaming.determineWinner(5, 4, true);

        Assert.equal(expected, result, "The player should have won by guessing the mystery number was higher than their number");
    }

    function testPlayerWonGuessLower() public {
        bool expected = true;
        bool result = gaming.determineWinner(5, 6, false);

        Assert.equal(expected, result, "The player should have won by guessing the mystery number was lower than their number");
    }

    function testPlayerLostGuessLower() public {
        bool expected = false;
        bool result = gaming.determineWinner(5, 4, false);

        Assert.equal(expected, result, "The player should have lost by guessing the mystery number was lower than their number");
    }

    function testPlayerLostGuessHigher() public {
        bool expected = false;
        bool result = gaming.determineWinner(5, 6, true);

        Assert.equal(expected, result, "The player should have lost by guessing the mystery number was higher than their number");
    }
}
```

**Error**
[image]

Comment: Refer this..
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/56533/onlyowner-and-testing-question

Comment: It is strange the error message is in the modifier `isOwner`, but that modifier isn't used at all in the code supplied. Can you try to narrow down to the exact code that is failing?